# How to find the error column for "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"

Tags: oracle

I get this error `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`, but I don't know what column. How can I find the column with the error?

```
INSERT INTO plants(created_at,updated_at,published,title,id_old,simplified_name,code,dp1,dh1,dh2,dh4,field9,migrate,lives_in_ro,is_endemic,is_international,is_national,priority,id_synonim,id_group,genus,id_tax_code,guid,vernacular_name,is_sensitive,id_red_list_codes,id_owner,insert_date,update_date,is_in_zoo,is4a,is5a,is5b,is4b,is_cites,is_bdv,is_ber,is_bon,is_new_record,is_for_derogation,id_inserter,berna1,bonn1,anexa_bonn,anexa_berna,berna2,berna3,bonn2,a17code,field47,field48,field49,taxup,incerta,spontan,cultivat,invaziva,al,turbarie,lr,l_rosie,lista_rosie,taxon,increngatura,clasa,ordin,familia,gen,specia,autor,subspecia,autor_ssp,varietatea,autor_var,forma,autor_for,ngexc,ngcateg,biblio,transferat,submited_checked
) VALUES(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0, 'Euclasta perisalis', '99012', 'perisalis', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '306200', '1', 'Euclasta', '200681', '8615DFE9-C28A-4240-B3A2-79D97ECCD41C', '', '0', '', '','00:00,0', '', '0', '0','0', '0','0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'D8446A30-8B8B-4059-AE3F-86AF0ABA39B8', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', 'Arthropoda', 'Insecta', 'Lepidoptera', 'Crambidae', 'Euclasta', 'varii', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0')
```

And here is the DLL

```
  DDL for Table PLANTS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."PLANTS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "DELETED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "PUBLISHED" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT '0', 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "DESCRIPTION" CLOB, 
    "ID_OLD" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "SIMPLIFIED_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DP1" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "DH1" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "DH2" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "DH4" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "FIELD9" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "MIGRATE" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "LIVES_IN_RO" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_ENDEMIC" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_INTERNATIONAL" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_NATIONAL" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "PRIORITY" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "ID_SYNONIM" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ID_GROUP" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "GENUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ID_TAX_CODE" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "GUID" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "VERNACULAR_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "IS_SENSITIVE" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "ID_RED_LIST_CODES" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ID_OWNER" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "INSERT_DATE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "UPDATE_DATE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "IS_IN_ZOO" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS4A" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS5A" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS5B" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS4B" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_CITES" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_BDV" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_BER" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_BON" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_NEW_RECORD" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "IS_FOR_DEROGATION" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "ID_INSERTER" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "BERNA1" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "BONN1" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "ANEXA_BONN" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ANEXA_BERNA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "BERNA2" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "BERNA3" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "BONN2" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "A17CODE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "FIELD47" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "FIELD48" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "FIELD49" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "TAXUP" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "INCERTA" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SPONTAN" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CULTIVAT" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "INVAZIVA" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "AL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TURBARIE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LR" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "L_ROSIE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LISTA_ROSIE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TAXON" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "INCRENGATURA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CLASA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ORDIN" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "FAMILIA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "GEN" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "SPECIA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "AUTOR" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "SUBSPECIA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "AUTOR_SSP" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "VARIETATEA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "AUTOR_VAR" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "FORMA" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "AUTOR_FOR" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "NGEXC" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "NGCATEG" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "BIBLIO" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "TRANSFERAT" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "SUBMITED_CHECKED" NUMBER(3,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" 
 LOB ("DESCRIPTION") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. In order for the community to be able to provide you with an adequate answer, you would have to supply us with more details. E.g. if you could provide us with the DDL for the table `plants`, then that would help us immensely. Click on [edit] and add additional details to your question. Currently your question might be closed as ***Needs details or clarity** - 
This question should include more details and clarify the problem.*.

Comment: PLEASE don't create Application tables into ANY of the Oracle-supplied Schemas! 
 Create your own Schemas (each within their own Tablespace, ideally) and create whatever you want inside those.  
None of us have any idea what Our Friends in Redwood City are going to do with their next upgrade and if they decide they want a table called PLANTS in their SYSTEM schema, then yours will be trashed.

Comment: Why do you enclose numeric values with quotes? That is bad practice. And you should **never** use `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE` (in your case `SYSDATE`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have a column typed as `NUMBER(precision, scale)` in the table `plants` where `precision` is the maximum total number of digits before and after the decimal point and `scale` is the number of digits after the decimal point. Look for such a column. A value you are inserting exceeds these limits.

Also, you are inserting most of the values as string enclosed in single quotes. Insert values into number columns without quotes. Even if it works in Oracle, it doesn't in other databases and it makes it difficult to detect numeric columns in the insert statement.

Now that you have added the table declaration, I see that you are inserting `'200681'` into `id_tax_code` which is typed as `NUMBER(5,0)` but the value has 6 digits (if I matched the columns right).

I also wonder why GUID columns are typed as `VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)`. They have a length of 36 characters.

And field names like `FIELD48` are terrible.

I also suggest inserting line breaks e.g., after every five columns and every five values in the insert statement. This makes it much easier to match columns and values:

```sql
INSERT INTO plants(
    created_at, updated_at, published, title, id_old,
    simplified_name, code, dp1, dh1, dh2,
    dh4, field9, migrate, lives_in_ro, is_endemic,
    is_international, is_national, priority, id_synonim, id_group,
    genus, id_tax_code, guid, vernacular_name, is_sensitive,
    --     ^^^^^^^^^^^
    id_red_list_codes, id_owner, insert_date, update_date, is_in_zoo,
    is4a, is5a, is5b, is4b, is_cites,
    is_bdv, is_ber, is_bon, is_new_record, is_for_derogation,
    id_inserter, berna1, bonn1, anexa_bonn, anexa_berna,
    berna2, berna3, bonn2, a17code, field47,
    field48, field49, taxup, incerta, spontan,
    cultivat, invaziva, al, turbarie, lr,
    l_rosie, lista_rosie, taxon, increngatura, clasa,
    ordin, familia, gen, specia, autor,
    subspecia, autor_ssp, varietatea, autor_var, forma,
    autor_for, ngexc, ngcateg, biblio, transferat,
    submited_checked
) VALUES(
    TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 0, 'Euclasta perisalis', '99012',
    'perisalis', '', '0', '0', '0',
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
    '0', '0', '0', '306200', '1',
    'Euclasta', '200681', '8615DFE9-C28A-4240-B3A2-79D97ECCD41C', '', '0',
    --          ^^^^^^^^
    '', '', '00:00,0', '', '0',
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
    'D8446A30-8B8B-4059-AE3F-86AF0ABA39B8', '0', '0', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '0',
    '', '', '', 'Arthropoda', 'Insecta',
    'Lepidoptera', 'Crambidae', 'Euclasta', 'varii', '',
    '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '',
    '0'
)
```

See also:

- [Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021)
- [Nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html). You should insert `NULL` instead of `''` for empty columns. Optionally, you could drop the column name from the columns list as well as the corresponding value from the values list. Columns that are not inserted explicitly will default to the column default value or NULL if no default value is specified.

Comment: For completeness would you like tomention DP1 as well.

Comment: `'0'` is inserted into `dp1` which is typed as `NUMBER(3,0)`. So, this should work (except that the apostrophes bother me).

Comment: My mistake, I miscounted the fields.